# Repeat image x number of times

Tags: php, image, loops

Hello I am working on a site that uses expedias api. Basically I get a number of people per room, and I want to echo out a little man image for each person. So if I have occupancy of 5 for example and I need to echo 5  tags with the little man as a src. Any idea how to do this??

Comment: this sort of thing might work http://jsfiddle.net/DampSquid/jsXbP/1/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well let's say you have the amount of people stored in a variable.

```
$occupancy = 5;
```

You can then plug in that number into a `for loop`, and have the program cycle through that many times.

```
for($n = 0; $n < $occupancy; $n++) {
  // Disco
}
```

You can read more about control structures [here](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.for.php).

Answer (score 1):

You should be interested in [`str_repeat()`](http://php.net/str-repeat).

Something like this should work:

```
$img_multi = str_repeat('<img src="man.png" alt="man"/>', $repeat);
echo $img_multi;
```

---

Revisiting this answer, a much more efficient solution:

Assuming the image is 12px wide by 16px high - adjust for your needs.

```
$width = 12 * $repeat;
$height = 16;
echo '<span style="'
           .'display: inline-block;'
           .'width: '.$width.'px;'
           .'height: '.$height.'px;'
           .'background-image: url(man.png);'
    .'"></span>';
```

This will produce a single element of the appropriate size to show `$repeat` copies of the image, side-by-side.